# Reverting DEIS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deis

I am trying to setup DEIS in AWS. So I am in the process of learning and it is expected that I will have to provision and setup many times before I master things.

Let's say I run provision-ec2-cluster and for some reason, I want to revert everything that was done in AWS (delete VPC, dele instances, scaling rules, security groups, etc.).

What is the easiest way to do that? Does Deis come with an script that can help me in this respect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ideal use case for AWS CloudFormation.  Either use the official Deis published info on CloudFormation at http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/installing_deis/aws/.  Note that with CloudFormation, you can with a single command launch all resources, or destroy all resources.

Or, alternatively, for a more sophisticated example with Terraform, a third-party alternative to CloudFormation, you can use something like https://github.com/brandfolder/infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks. I've never use cloudformation before though I used it as part of seting up Deis. Implicit in your answer was the suggestion that I should go to cloudformation and delete the stack.